# Read Amazon S3 specific folder from Azure databricks without public access to the bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, amazon-s3, pyspark, azure-databricks

Problem : Access specific directory contents present in an Amazon S3 bucket from databricks(pyspark)

Bucket policies setup

1. S3 bucket is not publicly accessible
2. Directory inside S3 bucket is granted permission for public access and contains parquet files.

Databricks setup on Azure

1. Databricks run time version 8.3
2. Spark version 3.1.1

Code snippet :

1. Set access key and secret key as

```py
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", access_key)
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", secret_key)
```

2. Read data in a dataframe from the directory

```py
AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME = BUCKET_NAME
 
read_df = spark.read \
    .format("parquet") \
    .option("header", "true") \
    .load("s3n://{}/{}".format(AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME, directory_name))
```

access_key, secret_key, BUCKET_NAME and directory_name are proper values.

> Error message : Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden;

Are there any properties to setup so as to read the specific directory contents from S3 bucket using Azure databricks when the S3 bucket is not publicly accessible?

Answer (score 0):

The ideal way to do this is to use AWS IAM roles to grant read-only access to buckets. The fundamental stages are as follows:

> 1. Make an IAM role for yourself.
> 2. Specify which users are allowed to take on the job.
> 3. Create a bucket policy that grants the role read-only access.
> 4. Using the dbutils.fs.mount command, mount the bucket to the
>    Databricks file system.
> 5. When you build the Databricks cluster, provide the IAM role

```html
access_key = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "aws", key = "aws-access-key")
secret_key = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "aws", key = "aws-secret-key")
encoded_secret_key = secret_key.replace("/", "%2F")
aws_bucket_name = "<aws-bucket-name>"
mount_name = "<mount-name>"

dbutils.fs.mount("s3a://%s:%s@%s" % (access_key, encoded_secret_key, aws_bucket_name), "/mnt/%s" % mount_name)
display(dbutils.fs.ls("/mnt/%s" % mount_name))
```

Where  you can access the file using :

```
df = spark.read.text("/mnt/%s/...." % MOUNT_NAME)
```

> **Note :** When you use keys to mount an S3 bucket, all users have read and write access to all of the S3 bucket's objects.